# OpenGL - ray placing

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have problem with ray placing object. I want to set model translation to the point where crosshair/reticle is indicates. Distance between camera position and object is fixed. I have actually only camera position and view matrix. I know how to calculate ray intersection using model matrix, camera matrix, but i don't know how to use raytracing.

Comment: I don't get the question... do you try to implement raytracing rendertechnique? maybe a picture would help me to understand what you mean... for raytracing you need the viewmatrix(camera position is in there) and projectionmatrix... if you try just to shoot a ray in the center of your screen (crosshair) then you don't need the projectionmatrix.

Comment: maybe you try to check if you hit (shot) something right? so if that is the case, you should use some kind of spacepartitioning (octree or AABB tree or KD-Tree) or if you do not have this much objects, you can test all. For these techniques you need a calculation for plane/ray intersection or even better cube/ray, sphere/ray or however your objects look like

Comment: i have function which checks if I indicates model with specific model matrix. I just multiply modelView matrix by 0,0,1 vector and calculate pitch and yaw using arctan. I want to do something similar but, I don't know model matrix. I want to place object where my reticle indicates based on sphere radius (orbit around camera position).